# Simple Capacitor charging and discharging question

Tags: capacitor, capacitor-charging

Below is a circuit consisting of a capacitor, voltage supply and resistors.
There is a switch that lets the capacitor charge and discharge.
I have also uploaded the given answers below;

I understand that for:

**(i)** **Tc**:     you find the thevenin resistance and multiply it by the capacitor value.

**(ii)** **Vc Max**: the voltage across the parralel (**Rz**) resistor.

**(iii)**: I am not sure that he has done there. Has he used the capacitor charge or discharge formula and rearranged it of some sort?

**(iv)**: Not sure what hes done here?

.
[image]

Comment: What is your specific question?

Comment: Despite the propaganda, there is nothing simple about charging and discharging capacitors. However that aside, what is your question?

Comment: Not sure how he has calculated III and IV part of the question

Comment: Im a bit confused about how he has calculated it in the answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure that he has done there. Has he used the capacitor charge or discharge formula and rearranged it of some sort?

The charging equation look like this:

$$V_C = V_{th}(1 - e^{\frac{-t}{RC}}) $$

Now to solve for the "time"\$(t)\$ we need to rearranged this formula.

First we can divide by \$V_{th}\$

$$\frac{V_C}{V_{th}} = 1 - e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} $$

We subtract 1 from both sides and multiply both sides by -1

$$\frac{V_C}{V_{th}} - 1 = - e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} $$

$$1-\frac{V_C}{V_{th}} = e^{\frac{-t}{RC}} $$

take the ln() of both sides

$$ln(1-\frac{V_C}{V_{th}}) = {\frac{-t}{RC}} $$

Multiply both sides by -RC

$$-RC*ln(1-\frac{V_C}{V_{th}}) = t $$

Swap sides

$$t = -RC*ln(1-\frac{V_C}{V_{th}})$$

> (iv): Not sure what hes done here?

\$t_d\$ is a discharge time constant \$t_d = R*C \$

Where \$R\$ is a resistance seen by the capacitor when discharging.

Comment: It makes total sense. Tried it with a few other questions and it works like a charm. Cheers