# Capacitor voltage equation (partially charged initial state)

Tags: voltage, capacitor, analog

Assuming we have a RC circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl7GcY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

We don't know the voltage of the capacitor but we know its voltage isn't greater than the battery voltage.

If the capacitor is completely  discharged when we close the switch \$ V_C = V_1(1 - e^{\frac {-t}{R_1 C_1}} )\$

If the capacitor is partially discharged (or charged if you see the cup half-full) can we derive a equation just like we did when it was discharged?
If this is the graph of charging a fully discharged capacitor and discharging a fully charged capacitor:

[image]

Is this the diagram of charging a partially charged capacitor and discharging a partially discharge capacitor?

[image]

Images from: [Electronics Tutorials - RC Charging Circuit Curves](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html)

Comment: well, yes, of course. Have you tried?

Comment: Hmm i am kind of new to this so I don't know much. I never understood the equations of the capacitors I just know how they work.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494435/a-capacitor-and-a-neon-lamp-focused-circuit-problem/494491#494491

Comment: Equations are in user287001 reply, the plot too. For a turn-key 3D simulator, it takes a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without teasing people with differential equations that can be seen in 1000 tutorials I suggest a practical method.

Let's assume the circuit is the same as in the question except there's already voltage Vo in the capacitor at t=0.

Think 1) the original charge decays to zero through R obeying Vo*exp(-t/RC) and at the same time 2) The capacitor is charged from zero charge towards V1 obeying your formula for V1

Present the total Vc as the sum of the parts:

Vc = Vo*exp(-t/RC) + V1(1-exp(-t/RC))

This can be marginally simplified by separating factor exp(-t/RC) but that's nothing remarkable except it gives another way to remember the result:

Vc = V1 - (V1-Vo)exp(-t/RC)

That Vc can be thought as "V1 - shortage". The shortage is the full difference V1-Vo at t=0 but dies off with time constant RC.

The next image shows an example. Vc (= the green curve) starts from Vo = 3 volts and approaches V1 = 10 volts. The time constant RC is 5 seconds :

[image]

The dotted lines show a practical drawing help. A line which continues with the initial growth rate reaches the final value in one time constant.

Comment: Can you plot me a graph and I will accept this answer.